# Github Actions build the same docker image regardless that I have uploaded a new Dockerfile

Tags: docker, github-actions

1. I've build a docker image using Git Actions, with a dockerfile uploaded. All good
2. I changed the Dockerfile, cleare all cache (action, docker build --no-cache) but it's still building the old image, as if the Dockerfile would be tha old (but as I know, it doesn't even exist anymore).

Help...

Answer (score 0):

Ahh the problem was that I commented out

```
docker pull ...
```

from my deployment script... :(